# UIkit Slideshow Element is covering the Navbar

Tags: html, css, uikit

I have my starter web-page as one, long, scrolling page. I'm using UIkit, and have added many elements successfully. I added a standard navbar at the top. My problem happens when I scroll down the page. Most elements scroll behind the bar as one would expect, but some of my elements scroll OVER the navbar - both pictures and text.

The elements that do this are using the `uk-slideshow` property.

Here is the HTML for the two elements in question:

```
 <!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="uk-navbar" data-uk-sticky>
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the slideshow ...

```
<ul class="uk-slideshow" data-uk-slideshow="{autoplay:true}">
  <li>
    <div class="person">Sara
      <img src="images/agent_p2.jpg" class="id">
      <p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>             
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The uk-navbar within Uikit didn't have a z-index assigned. Added a z-index to the nav and it fixed the problem.